# Azure AD authentication failing via Auth0

Tags: azure-active-directory, auth0

I've got an app registered in Azure AD.  And I've configured the connector in Auth0.  When I push the 'Try It' button in Auth0, I'm prompted with

```
Neo Dev

Neo Dev needs permission to access resources in your organization that 
only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to 
this app before you can use it.

Have an admin account? Sign in with that account
Return to the application without granting consent
```

But in Azure AD I've already used the button labeled:

```
Grant consent
As an administrator, you can grant consent on behalf of all users 
in this directory. Granting admin consent for all users means that 
end users will not be shown a consent screen when using the application.
```

So obviously I'm missing something.  Any ideas what I should check next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by adding Directory.Read.All and User.Read from *both* **Microsoft Graph** permissions AND **Legacy Azure Active Directory Graph** permissions.